# Realloc function in C

Tags: c

Say I have this piece of code,

```
void string_copy(char *value)
{
    char *begin = value;
    char *temp = NULL;
    char result[1000] = {'\0'};

    //get_result will return the length of result
    int length = get_result(result);

    if (length >= strlen(begin))
    {
        temp =  realloc(begin, length+1);
        if (temp)
        {
            begin = temp;
            strncpy(begin, result, length);
            begin[length] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
      strncpy(begin, result, length);
      begin[length] = '\0';
    }
    return;
}


void test_function()
{
    char *value;
    value = calloc(1, 10);
    string_copy(value);
    printf("value = %s\n", value);
}
```

Say, if I have such a function, wherein I pass a character pointer to get the data copied from another function, and I do "begin=realloc(xxx...)" If I find that the space I allocated in the test function is shorter than the length of result. Will it change the size of the 'value' as well?

I am getting a memory leakage error when I assign "begin" with "temp".

How can I fix it?

Comment: What makes you doubt the correctness?

Comment: `begin =  realloc(1, length+1);` why do you think the first argument to realloc is an int?

Comment: `realloc(1, length+1)` -- Is this a typo? You're passing `1` as a pointer?

Comment: yes. corrected it. All I want is to resize the pointer begin to be able to hold the result in it.

Comment: `begin` is  a local variable and the reallocation does not find its way out of the function.

Comment: How is `get_result` any better than `gets`?

Comment: @Barmar I deleted my comments, you can delete you's too, thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't necessarily change `value`. `realloc()` is allowed to extend the length of an existing allocation, or create a new allocation and free the old one. You need to assign the returned pointer back to `value`.

Change `string_copy` to return the new pointer.

```
char * string_copy(char *value)
{
     char *begin = value;
     char result[1000] = {'\0'};

     //get_result will return the length of result
     int length = get_result(result);

     if (length >= strlen(begin)) 
     {
         begin =  realloc(begin, length+1);
     }
     strncpy(begin, result, length);
     begin[length] = '\0';

     return begin;
}

void test_function()
{
    char *value;
    value = calloc(1,10);
    value = string_copy(value);
    printf("value = %s\n", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you could/should add is the ability to handle a failure of `realloc`. However, by assigning the return value to the same pointer given as the first argument (very common practice, BTW), you lose the ability to properly do this - as you will have assigned `NULL` to your 'old' pointer and the memory it used to point to can not be freed.

Better code is something like this:

```c
if (length >= strlen(begin)) 
{
    char* temp = realloc(begin, length+1);
    if (temp == NULL) { // Realloc failed, but we still have our old pointer in "begin"
        // Handle the error condition (may require "free(begin)")
    }
    else {
        begin = temp; // Now we can replace the old pointer with our new one
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will do this. Could you please help me understand if it is okay to free the 'temp' anywhere after this?

Comment: If the `realloc` call fails, `temp` (which will be `NULL`) can be forgotten about. If the call succeeds, then - as you copy its value (the address of the new memory block) into `begin`, you can also forget about it, as the information you need is now in `begin` - but you ***must not*** free it locally, or `begin` will then point to invalid memory! (Hope that's clear!)

Comment: I am getting memory leak message. And unfortunately I cannot afford them . Any help how I can fix it. I am getting the message from the static analyzer saying (20) Event var_assign:  Assigning: "begin" = "temp".
Also see events:  [alloc_fn][var_assign][noescape][leaked_storage][leaked_storage]. I tried freeing 'begin' before assigning it with 'temp'. But it was resulting in segmentation fault.

Comment: string_copy is called passing an array whose zeroth element is NUL, so in string_copy,  strlen(begin) will always be zero. The ensuing realloc will likely lead to a memory leak.

Comment: @PoornimaM There are, to be honest, several problems in your code. First and foremost, read the answer given by Barmar. Then (and only then) try to understand what I've suggested here. Seems to me that you don't appreciate what a pointer is - I can try (but not here) to explain, but *you* have to make *some* effort.

Comment: @PoornimaM PS: Your "static analyser" is probably being a wee bit too severe - in the code I posted, `temp` is checked for `NULL` before it's assigned to anything.

Comment: @FredK - Calling `realloc` with a `NULL` pointer as 1st argument equivalates to calling `malloc`; so, as long as the return value is checked, no memory leak.

Comment: @FredK Aah, OK, calling it with a size argument of zero can cause UB.