# C memory leak after freeing string that has been realloc'd multiple times

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks, clion

I am trying to create a program that reads different movies from a large file and sorts them in different ways. I have run into a problem with a particularly stubborn memory leak - one that has resisted my attempts to fix it.

Without further ado, here is the function where valgrind says the memory leak happens.

```
static int isValidAnimatedMovie(char * genre, unsigned int votes){
    if (votes < MIN_VOTES_ANIMATED)
        return 0;

    char * line;
    char * resp = NULL;
    int c;
    unsigned long len=0;
    int flag = 0;
    line = strtok(genre,GDIV);
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_GENRES && line != NULL; i++){
        c = strcmp("Animation", line);

        if (c != 0){
            len+= strlen(line)+1;      
            if (resp == NULL){
                resp = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
                if (resp == NULL || errno == ENOMEM){
                    perror("Memory ERROR in isValidAnimatedMovie");
                }
                strcpy(resp, line);
            }

            else{
                resp = realloc(resp, (len+1)+1);
                if (resp == NULL || errno == ENOMEM){
                    perror("Memory ERROR in isValidAnimatedMovie");
                }
                resp = strcat(resp, line);
            }   
            resp = strcat(resp, GDIV);     
        }

        if (c<0 && flag==0){    
            return 0;
        }
        else if (c==0)       
            flag=1;
        line = strtok(NULL,GDIV);

    }
    resp[len-1]=0;
    strcpy(genre,resp);       
    free(resp);
    return flag;
}
```

The function receives a string called genres. This string has all of the movie's genres separated by GDIV (a comma) and in alphabetical order. An example would be "Action,Adventure,Animation,Comedy".

What this function is supposed to do is check whether a movie has enough votes and, if it has the word "Animation" in the string genres, it should remove it so that the final result looks like "Action,Adventure,Comedy" if I feed it the example string.

That works wonderfully. What happens here is that even though I free the pointer resp at the end of the function, valgrind still detects a memory leak, even though I've freed the pointer. It says the following.

Direct leak of 37666 byte(s) in 2042 object(s) allocated from:

Then this function, with the line in which the malloc happens highlighted. It also displays the realloc in the same way.

I have tried different things to solve this. I have tried to set resp to NULL after freeing it, and I have also tried to use strncpy instead of the final strcpy. However, none of those things have solved my problem.

I have noticed that after freeing it, resp still shows up in the debugger as "/001". Is that a clue as to what could have gone wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: JS snippets are useful tool for html/css/js questions.  They should not be used for other code though.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Code like `resp = realloc(resp, (len+1)+1);` is a common cause of memory leaks. Once that call has failed, you've completely lost the original pointer. [An answer I posted a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074663/10871073).

Comment: `if (c<0 && flag==0){ return 0;` exits from the function without callling `free(resp)`. Have you checked whether that `return` is being hit?

Comment: Instead of a long wordy description of code that we can already read for ourselves it would be better if you provide a complete [mre], the exact valgrind output and the exact input. That would allow us to run and reproduce the problem ourselves. Please provide that if you still need further help.

Comment: You are allocating one less byte with `malloc` than `realloc`. Is that an issue? To simplify, eliminate the `malloc` [and associated `if/else`] and just do `realloc` all the time. It handles a null pointer arg just fine [by definition].

Comment: It is perfectly possible to do this with *one* allocation, at the size `strlen(genre) + 1`, and no reallocations. The string is not going to grow. (It is also possible to do this with no allocations at all, although it could get a bit messy).

Comment: The function exited without calling free(resp) if it returned 0. Thank you all very much, this issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The leak is here:

```
    if (c<0 && flag==0){    
        return 0;
    }
```

To fix it:

```
    if (c<0 && flag==0){
        free(resp);    
        return 0;
    }
```